I'm searching for a solution to open the game
I was install an UE4 game, I already have DirectX but when I open the game, it's all black, and then this pop out.
fatal error [file unknown] [line: 1168]
Gamethread timed out waiting for Renderthread after 120.00 secs.
the game I play is an UE4 fashion game in Epic Games launcher.
help please. sorry I'm bad at this kind of computer stuffs.
thank you.
still trying to figure it out

Welcome to Stack Overflow! It appears this question is about trying to play a video game. Stack Overflow is more of a programming based site rather than a video game site. See what topics can I ask here?
